# cssSandpaper.js help needed?

Tags: javascript

For a small project I am using the rotate js library found: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/ [cssSandpaper.js](http://90.197.69.193/notes/js/cssSandpaper.js) (line 308)

Line:  `me.identity = $M([[1, 0], [0, 1]]);`

Unfortunaly im getting $M is not defined, Im not brilliant at understanding loads and loads of javascript (although I can understand my own code fine) so could anyone think of a way of fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will receive this error if you are not including the 'sylvester.js' file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jcoglan.com/sylvester.js"></script>
```

Make sure the path you are using to include the file is correct.

Comment: Thanks, its people like you who make it possible to use google as a method of getting answers. Even though I since have finished my project using a different method I'm sure if anyone has the problem in the future they'll be able to find what they are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly why I posted, despite knowing full well you would have had some sort of solve by now. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. But none of the solutions here solved it for me.

What I had to do to make it work was to load the Js files in this exact order:

- EventHelpers.js
- cssQuery-p.js
- sylvester.js
- cssSandpaper.js

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error as well.
In my case, I have the reference to `jcoglan.com/sylvester.js` correctly.
However, I got this error only when I run the script from the server, I do not get the error if I run from local machine.  I have learned that it cannot find the path  in `jcoglan.com` folder.  I had do remove the `.com` portion.